# How do I cleanly avoid creating a context menu inside a context menu?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am adding a context menu to my window, and I seem to have discovered a quirk of Win32: because a popup menu forwards mouse messages to its owner window, and the default behavior of WM_RBUTTONUP is to send WM_CONTEXTMENU, if you open a popup menu in the handler for WM_CONTEXTMENU, you can right-click the menu to open another one. This fails because a menu is already open.

This seems like a really obvious, common bug but [even the official WM_CONTEXTMENU guide from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-menus#processing-the-wm_contextmenu-message) doesn't even mention it. Nor does any other tutorial.

**So, what is the cleanest way to *not* try to open a popup menu inside another one?**

Of course, one can simply add a global flag to indicate that a menu is open, but that's not clean. One can also ignore the error from `TrackPopupMenuEx`, but that's also not clean. I can't imagine that the Win32 (horrendous as it is) would encourage programmers to do such things.

---

I investigated how some common controls behave:

- The edit control doesn't pass WM_RBUTTONUP to DefWindowProc unless it received a previous WM_RBUTTONDOWN. Because the menu system handles WM_RBUTTONDOWN internally and does not dispatch it, this means it doesn't pass WM_RBUTTONUP to DefWindowProc when a menu is open.
- The tree view in the Microsoft Management Console creates a temporary window to associate the menu with.
- The details list view in Task Manager does receive a recursive WM_CONTEXTMENU; I assume that it tries to create the menu and ignores the error.

---

This test program demonstrates the phenomenon:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

static LRESULT CALLBACK window_proc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(msg) {
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        return 0;
    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
        std::cout << "got WM_RBUTTONDOWN\n";
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    case WM_RBUTTONUP:
        std::cout << "got WM_RBUTTONUP\n";
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    case WM_CONTEXTMENU:
        std::cout << "got WM_CONTEXTMENU\n";
        {
            HMENU hm = CreatePopupMenu();
            AppendMenu(hm, MF_STRING, 1234, L"Hello");
            AppendMenu(hm, MF_STRING, 4321, L"world");
            POINT pt;
            GetCursorPos(&pt);
            SetLastError(0);
            int res = TrackPopupMenuEx(hm, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_TOPALIGN | TPM_NONOTIFY | TPM_RETURNCMD, pt.x, pt.y, hwnd, NULL);
            int err = GetLastError();
            std::cout << "TrackPopupMenuEx returned " << res << ", error " << err << std::endl;
            SetLastError(0);
        }
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

int main()
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcx = {0};
    wcx.cbSize = sizeof wcx;
    wcx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    wcx.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcx.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcx.hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = window_proc;
    wcx.lpszClassName = L"TestWindowClass";
    RegisterClassEx(&wcx);
    CreateWindowEx(0, wcx.lpszClassName, L"Popup menu message test", WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 300, 300, NULL, NULL, wcx.hInstance, NULL);
    
    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So nothing happens when you right-click.  As expected, failure is a feature.

Comment: If you supply the flag `TPM_RIGHTBUTTON` then the right button will be used to select a menu item, not initiate a nested `WM_CONTEXTMENU` message.

Comment: @HansPassant Sure, one can just ignore the error when showing the second context menu. That is not very clean. Is there an alternative method that is?

Comment: Menus are not supposed to be recursive the way you describe, unless you explicitly ask for that behavior via the TPM_RECURSE flag and handling of the WM_MENURBUTTONUP message

Comment: Not related to the problem but `GetCursorPos` is wrong, the LPARAM tells you the correct location. (The mouse can move after the click but before you get the message)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Exactly. They're not supposed to be, yet the system tries to make them, by default. What's the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `TrackPopupMenu` is one of those functions that nobody ever checks for errors. After all, as long as the input parameters are valid, it is only going to fail (in the normal non-recursive case) if you are out of resources (memory or gdi/user handles). And if it fails, `MessageBox` is probably also going to fail so you can't even inform the user.

The normal coding pattern is to just check for your menu command IDs and ignore everything else.

The `TPM_RECURSE` flag which was added in the IE 4/5 era allows you to put a popup menu on a popup menu but nobody ever does that.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackpopupmenuex)

> ##### TrackPopupMenuEx
>
> ...
> If you specify TPM_RETURNCMD in the fuFlags parameter, the return
> value is the menu-item identifier of the item that the user selected.
> If the user cancels the menu without making a selection, or **if an
> error occurs**, the return value is zero.

If popup menu is already open and user right-clicked it, or the user cancels the menu, the function returns `FALSE`. In either case you don't want to process the result, so just return immediately. If `res` is non-zero, process it.

```
BOOL res = TrackPopupMenuEx(hm, 
    TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_TOPALIGN | TPM_NONOTIFY | TPM_RETURNCMD,
    pt.x, pt.y, hwnd, NULL);
if (!res) return 0;
std::cout << "Menu selection: " << res << "\n";
```

Or you can use `GetLastError` to find the reason for failure. Was it because user canceled, right-click the menu, or something else

```
if (!res)
{
    int err = GetLastError();
    if (err != 0 && err != ERROR_POPUP_ALREADY_ACTIVE)
        std::cout << "Unexpected error " << err << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question was for a clean way to write this without just ignoring an error. I may accept this answer if there really is no better way than to ignore an error.